# How do I change one parameter in different json items in js?

Tags: javascript, json

Ok, I have json with two objects:

```
    products = null;
    products = JSON.parse(result.content).products;    
    console.log(products);
```

The console.log(products); gives me this data:

```
[Object, Object]
  0: Object
    description: "<p>it's what you need</p>"
    name: "wow product"
    preview_url: "erl.jpg"
    price: "21000"
  1: Object
    description: "<p>okok</p>"
    name: "wow nemr"
    preview_url: "surl.jpg"
    price: "25000"
```

What I need is to change all prices from cents to dollars, something like `products.each.price = this.price / 100` before the `console.log(products);`
, but don't understand, how to operate with multiple ojects in one json. Point me to the right direction, please.

Comment: What about a simple `for` loop ?

Answer (score 1):

```
products.forEach(function (product) {
    product.price = product.price / 100;
});
```